# MongoDB cumulative grouping over time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Ok so I want to get a cumulative count of types of items added by date (month/year)

I am able to get the grouping by month/year and type...and my Number (sum) gives me the count for THAT month... but what Im after is THAT month PLUS all the previous months...

Here is what I have so far

```
Things.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'dates.added': {
                $ne: null
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
            year: {
                $year: '$dates.added'
            },
            month: {
                $month: '$dates.added'
            },
            type: '$type'
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            '_id.year': -1,
            '_id.month': -1,
            '_id.type': 1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 100,
    },
])
```

Which yields a result like this

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2018,
        "month" : 9,
        "type" : "Train"
    },
    "number" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2018,
        "month" : 9,
        "type" : "Car"
    },
    "number" : 1.0
}


{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2018,
        "month" : 9,
        "type" : "Boat"
    },
    "number" : 1.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2018,
        "month" : 8,
        "type" : "Car"
    },
    "number" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2018,
        "month" : 8,
        "type" : "Boat"
    },
    "number" : 2.0
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2018,
        "month" : 8,
        "type" : "Train"
    },
    "number" : 1.0
}
```

Or to put it another way:

```
        Aug-18      Sep-18
Boat:   2           1
Car:    2           1
Train:  1           1
```

But what Im after is this (cumulative)

```
        Aug-18      Sep-18
Boat:   2           3
Car:    2           3
Train:  1           2
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add a `$project` stage and project year, type and month, but for month use [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) to output an array with all months from actual month to end of year
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the months array
- `$group` by year, month and type and use `$sum`

Aggregation pipeline:

```
Things.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'dates.added': {
                $ne: null
            }
        }
    },{
        $project: {
            year: {
                $year: '$dates.added'
            },
            month: {
                $range: [ { "$month" : '$dates.added'}  , 13 ]
            },
            type: '$type'
        }
    },{
        $unwind: "$month",
    },{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year:"$year",
                month: "$month",
                type: '$type'
            },
            number : { $sum : 1 }
        }
    },{
        $sort: {
            '_id.year': -1,
            '_id.month': -1,
            '_id.type': 1
        }
    },{
        $limit: 100,
    },
])
```